# Customized list cross reference error

Tags: cross-referencing, lists

I have created a customized list environment in the `book` class. The labels for the list are produced the way I want, but when items are referenced, they are not labeled correctly. Here is the code. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]
\usepackage{amsfonts,fancyhdr,amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,graphicx}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage[neverdecrease]{paralist}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,latexsym,graphicx}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\renewcommand{\theenumi} {\arabic{enumi}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\theenumi}
\renewcommand{\theenumii} {\alph{enumii}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\theenumii}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{(\theenumii)}
%\renewcommand{\p@enumi}{\theenumi--}

\newcommand{\mynonsense}
{
\vspace{1cm}\begin{center}{\scshape\large Nonsense}\end{center}\vspace{2pt}\noindent
}

\setdefaultleftmargin{4em}{3em}{1.87em}{1.7em}{1em}{1em}

\newenvironment{mylist}
{\pagestyle{plain}
\setdefaultleftmargin{2em}{3em}{1.87em}{1.7em}{1em}{1em}
\setlength{\topsep}{3.mm}
\setdefaultenum{1$\;$}{a$\;$}{i$\;$}{A$\;$}
\bigskip
\begin{compactenum}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\thechapter-\arabic{enumi}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\thechapter-\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}}

\setlength{\itemsep}{3.mm}
\setlength{\topsep}{3.mm}}
{\end{compactenum}
\bigskip
}


\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\mynonsense % command which produces header
\begin{mylist}
\item \label{1} item 1-1
\item \label{2} item 1-2
\begin{mylist}
\item \label{2a1} item 1-2.1
\item \label{2a2} item 1-2.2
\end{mylist}
\item \label{3} item 1-3
\begin{compactenum}[(a)]
\item \label{a} item 1-3a
\item \label{b} item 1-3b
\end{compactenum}
\end{mylist}
Labels print out as \ref{1}, \ref{2}, \ref{2a1}, \ref{2a2}, \ref{3}, \ref{a},
\ref   {b},  which  is wrong.  Correct is (1-1), (1-2), (1-2.1), (1-2.2) (1-3),
(1-3a), (1-3b).
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you have a look at the `enumitem` package that's more powerful than `paralist`?

Answer (score 3):

`\labelenumi` and similars only change how the label is presented. In order to change the actual representation of the counter (which is referenced by the `\label` and `\ref` commands), you need to replace your `\labelenumi` and `\labelenumii` with `\theenumi` and `\theenumii` respectively in your custom environment.

Just changing those right after the `\begin{compactenum}` line did it for me in your example text.